# When two isomorphic subgroups are conjugate?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I would like where could I find a reference in which this question is answered.

Let us consider $H,H'\leq G$ two isomorphic subgroups of a Lie group $G\in \{\mathbf{SO}(n),\mathbf{SU}(n),\mathbf{Sp}(n)\}$. When can we ensure that $H$ is conjugate to $H'$ in $G$?

I know that if these subgroups are maximal among connected proper subgroups and $G\in \{\mathbf{SU}(n),\mathbf{Sp}(n)\}$, they must be conjugate. Some more particular questions related to this are the following:

---

(1) When can we ensure that two isomorphic subgroups which are maximal among connected proper subgroups, are conjugate in $\mathbf{SO}(n)$?

(2) For instance, is there some way to see how many subgroups of $\mathbf{SO}(2n)$ are isomorphic to $\mathbf{U}(n)$ up to conjugation?

Comment: Could you be more precise by "maximal"? Do you mean (maximal among proper subgroups and connected) or "maximal among connected proper subgroups"?

Comment: I was thinking about the second: maximal among connected proper subgroups. Would it be a big difference with respect to the first one?

Comment: Yes it makes a big difference, just think of subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Comment: But in this case, I don't see the difference. If you have a subgroup of $\mathbf{SO}(3)$  maximal among proper subgroups and connected must be isomorphic to $\mathbf{SO}(2)$ and if it is maximal among connected proper subgroups must be isomorphic to $\mathbf{SO}(2)$, either.

Comment: The difference is that $\mathbf{SO}(2)$ is (maximal proper connected), but is not maximal proper (it's contained as subgroup of index 2 in its normalizer).

Comment: Ok now I understand, I will edit the question.

Comment: For (2), classifying $2n$-dimensional reps of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ should make some cleaning. For $n\ge 6$, there's only combinations of the standard rep $V$, its dual, and copies of the trivial 1-dim rep, and requiring the existence of a non-degenerate invariant quadratic form narrows to $V\oplus V^*$ and the trivial $2n$-dim rep. This should imply that the only possible embedding $\mathfrak{su}(n)\to\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ is the standard one. I haven't looked at $3\le n\le 5$ but the list of maximal proper subalgebras of $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ up to conjugation should be known.

Comment: What's a reference for the statement for the case $G\in \{SU(n), Sp(n)\}$?

Comment: @YCor:  If you don't mind, I'm still struggling with your proof sketch that my answer was wrong.  Is the result that the normalizer of $U(n)$ is the normalizer of $\langle J\rangle$ some kind of general property of normalizers-of-centralizers, or something unique to this $U(n)$?  Also, it's still not clear to me why this would force the index to be at most 2.  (I do understand the result of the argument.  Sorry to continue to be a bother, and thanks for your time!)

Comment: @JasonDeVito call J-element an element $J$ satisfying $J^2=-1$, and let $J_0$ be the multiplication by $i$. Then the only J-elements $J$ in $\mathrm{GL}_{2n}(\mathbf{R})$ preserved by $U(n)$ are $J_0^{\pm 1}$ (this is because first $J$ commutes with $J_0$, hence belongs to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{C})$; since $U(n)$ acts irreducibly its centralizer therein is reduced to scalars, i.e., $\mathbf{C}^*$, in which these are the only elements squaring to $-1$). The normalizer of $U(n)$ preserves the set of J-elements preserved by $U(n)$ (this is general), and hence this $\{J_0^{\pm 1}\}$ pair.

Comment: @YCor:  It doesn't seem to be true that a J-element in $\mathrm{GL}_{2n}(\mathbf{R})$ necessarily commutes with $J_0$ (though certainly all J-elements in $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbf{C})$ do!).  Consider $J_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2\\ -1/2 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$  Anyway, I'll continue to think about this tomorrow.  (If you'd like to continue via email, I'd be happy to.  I'm also happy to continue in the comments, but the OP may be getting sick of all the pings.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito I didn't say this. I said that a J-element $J$ **preserved by $U(n)$** has to commute with $J_0$. That $J$ is preserved by $U(n)$ means that $J$ centralizes $U(n)$. Since $U(n)$ contains the "scalar" matrix $J_0$, $J$ has to commute with $J_0$. (Better here than email for me – if the discussion becomes longer the system will propose the chat mode)

Comment: @YCor:  Your last message was all I needed - sorry for misunderstanding your previous claim.  And thanks for your patience.   (And for when I read this in the future: if $A,B\in N_{O(2n)}(\langle J_0\rangle)\setminus \langle J_0\rangle$, then it's easy to compute that $AB$ commutes with $J_0$, hence $AB\in U(n)$, hence $U(n)\subseteq N_{O(2n)}(\langle J_0\rangle)$ has index at most $2$.  Since $U(n)\subseteq N_{O(2n)}(U(n))\subseteq N_{O(2n)}(\langle J_0\rangle)$, the index $2$ claim now follows.)